# Beanstalkd running all jobs in the queue simultaneously on forge queue workers

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen, beanstalkd, forge

I'm running an API build on Laravel Lumen 5.1, but I can't seem to get the Forge Queue Worker to work properly when using beanstalkd as a driver. It seems to run all the jobs in the queue simultaneously

I'm using the Forge UI to set up the driver

[Queue Worker setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFCKK.png)

And the .env drivers
[The .env drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88rm.png)

The queue system works fine when running it manually without any worker processing it.

If you need any more informations to help me, please just ask!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the message queue is to allow parallel processing. If you have more workers eg: more threads than it will run simultaneously as many jobs.

In order to achieve non simultaneously that is counter intuitive and against the message queue principle. You can achieve that with 1 single worker, but it's not recommended as you don't leverage the power and scalability.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my problem. I only have a single queue worker, which is on purpose as the job it's handling is rather large, and I don't want to overload the server. The problem is that it's running all jobs simultaneously instead of waiting for each job to finish, before it starts the next.

Comment: What's the TTR (time to resolve) you set for your jobs. The default is usually 60 seconds, and if your worker doesn't finish, the beanstalkd server will give the same job to another instance of workers.